# C# Array Extention Methods with Reference Type - how to change reference

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I'm working in Unity, and I have arrays of different types which I need to check and manipulate. After some issues with the Reference Type I found the following solution:

I have created the class "ArrayHelper" like this

```
public class ArrayHelper {
    public static void TrimArray<T>(ref T[] array)
    {
        T[] newArray = new T[array.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = newArray;
    }
}
```

And I use this method like this:

```
void Start()
{
    ArrayHelper.TrimArray(ref myArray);
}
```

While this works, I don't think it is really elegant. I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650831/how-to-add-methods-to-manipulate-an-array-of-class-objects) where they show how I could do this instead:

```
void Start()
{
    nextPaths.Trim();
}
```

To do this I have changed the ArrayHelper class to this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensionMethods {
    public static void Trim<T>(this T[] array)
    {
        T[] newArray = new T[array.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = newArray;
    }
}
```

When I call the method it doesn't change the array. I suspect this is due to references. Is there a way where I can manipulate my array like this which works properly?

**Note:** There are also other methods in the 'ArrayExtensionMethods' which can manipulate the array in way more complex ways. Therefore I'm looking for a general solution to my problem instead of a solution which I can only use to replace the "Trim()" method.

Comment: `Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - 1);`

Comment: public static T[] Trim<T>(this T[] array){ ..... return newArray;}

Comment: @Dmitry you [can't reassign the `array` parameter](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZyrQap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer ref:

```cs
        public static void Trim<T>(this T[] array, ref T[] output)
        {
            T[] newArray = new T[array.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
            {
                newArray[i] = array[i];
            }
            output = newArray;
        }
```

Use:

```cs
a.Trim(ref a);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, basically. You can't use `ref` on an extension method's first parameter unless it is a value-type. You'll have to return the array instead. Or... use a `List<T>` instead of a naked `T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Ref extension methods, abysmally documented and unclear when they were introduced exactly (somewhere between C# 7.0 and 7.2), only operate on structs.

See for example [C# 7.2 ref/in extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref#refin-extension-methods).

[An array is not a struct, it's a reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type).

So no, you can't do this.